# momentjs getting the version number to display on my help about screen

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

We want to display the version number from momentjs and several other products. I am new to javascript (actually doing almost everything with TypeScript).

I can see there is a VERSION and a moment.version. But I can't seem to access either of them, the VS TypeScript tells me they are visible.

```
 (function (undefined) {

/************************************
    Constants
************************************/

var moment,
    VERSION = "2.1.0",
    round = Math.round, i,
    // internal storage for language config files
    languages = {},
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting. I've updated the defs : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/1897

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the definition from [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/moment/moment.d.ts), it would appear that the `version` property was left off from the list of static properties. You can easily extend it by including it either in the original definition, or because interfaces in TypeScript are extensible, you can add the missing property by declaring the `interface` in one of your files with the version property.

```
interface MomentStatic {
    version: string;
}
```

Because the `moment` global variable is defined to be the `interface` `MomentStatic` in the definition file:

```
declare var moment: MomentStatic;
```

You won't need to do anything other than add the version property as shown above.

Now, you can use:

```
var ver : string = moment.version; // currently 2.5.1 for example
```